# physical location of localstorage in android mobile?

Tags: android

I am wondering where is physical location of localstorage in android mobile.

can anybody tell me where android native browser stores its localstorage values?

and is it possible store webview localstorage value to android native browser

localstorage db by setting webview databasepath to physical location of android native browser

localsotrage db?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very clear question.

Most Android browsers would store things in their application's private directory.  On a secured device, other apps (or even the owner) can only access that by working through interfaces exposed (or files set world readable) by the browser application in question.

Anything you do with a webview in your own application happens under the userid of the application process hosting the webview.  Thus any private storage would be in your application's private directory.  Even though you might be using some of the same underlying webview code as an installed browser, the fact that you are running as a different application userid means you will have no special access to the browser application's private data.